# Why does the Python console repeat back what input into it?

Tags: python, object, numbers

When I write something into the python console, it repeats back what I write.

Like if I write 1, it displays 1 in output, and if I write True it gives True.

Why is this?

Example:

```
>>1
1

>>True
True
```

What actually happens in background?

Comment: And if you type, for example, `1+1` ?

Answer (score 3):

You're typing into a [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). It **R**eads input, **E**valuates it, **P**rints the result, then **L**oops back and starts again.

You're having it read the number `1`, evaluate it (although it's just a number), then print the result of the evaluation (the number). After that it waits for more input to be entered so it can run again.

If you typed a more complicated expression, it would be evaluated as well. `1 + 1` will show `2`, and `[1] * 5` will show `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` for example.

If you want to think about how this is achieved in terms of code, the most basic implementation of a REPL would be something along the lines of:

```
while True:
    user_input = input(">> ")

    result = eval(user_input) # eval evaluates a string as code

    print(result)
```

Code similar to this (although likely far more complicated) is just running in the background.

Comment: is REPL a function to which, the value or something we type is passed to?

Comment: It's just a program that runs. Just a sec. I was about to have a shower, but I thought of how this can be though of in terms of code.

Comment: @Randy REPL is terminology, a way to describe a tool that does a thing (and the "thing" is explained in Carcigenicate's answer, with the aid of bold characters). It's not some specific special function in some specific language.

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about [one way to invoke the Python interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#tut-invoking).

This is a computer program designed to accept Python statements, and to print the evaluated result of each one.

In your examples, your statements are simple expressions that evaluate to pretty much what you typed in.

More complex examples include expressions like `1+1`, or function calls.

*How* this works "in [the] background" is far too large a topic for a Stack Overflow answer, but you could study the Python project's source code if you really wanted to know what kind of programming constructs have been used to produce this computer program.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just a little info. Do the number or something we type passed as a value to some default function ?

Comment: @Randy I don't understand the question. The computer program accepts input, processes it, and returns output. Who cares what the function is called in that computer program's source code? I don't really follow what it is that you're trying to discover.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer:

Jeffrey Elkner in [his book](http://www.openbookproject.net/books/bpp4awd/ch02.html#statements-and-expressions) says that:

> When you type a statement on the command line, Python executes it. The interpreter does not display any results....
> An expression is a combination of values, variables, operators, and calls to functions. **If you type an expression at the Python prompt, the interpreter evaluates it and displays the result, which is always a value**

---

### More details:

You know, what a computer really understands is consecutive zero's and one's.
Your hardware is the one who specifies the format of these one's and zero's.
it is hard for people to know about how to order a hardware to do a task. To solve this problem,high level languages and [**VHLL**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_high-level_programming_language)(very high-level programming languages) **such as Python** are created.

How do they solve the problem?
These languages are more similar to human languages. In addition, each of these languages has some tool to convert the code to a machine-readable format! (of course, without this, they were worth nothing)

Actually the tools used to convert a human-readable format to machine-readable format, fall into one of these categories: **Interpreters**, Compilers, Hybrid approach(used in languages like C# and Java).

**Python code is executed using an Interpreter!**
So when you type an **expression** or an **statement**, in python shell, the interpreter comes and executes the statements and evaluates the expressions in your code!

One final point:
[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html) considers expressions, just as a subset of statements(look at the link).